# Typedef STL Containers c++

Tags: c++

I need to choose between `std::vector` and `std::list` depending on the `bool` value.

For example:

```
template<bool VAL>
class A
{
    typedef typename IF<VAL,std::vector,std::list>::RET data_t;
    
    private:
    B<data_t> _container;
};



template<bool g, class T, typename E>
struct IF
{
    typedef T RET;
};

template<class T, typename E>
struct IF<false, T, E>
{
    typedef E RET;
};

template <template <class, class> class Container>
class B
{
};
```

Errors:

> Error  1   error C3203: 'vector' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type
>
> Error  2   error C3203: 'list' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'E', expected a real type

Comment: You need to learn how to indent things, is what you need to do. And what are `stl::vector`/`stl::list`? You'll find that programming is much easier if you pay _any_ attention whatsoever to the most obvious details.

Comment: My god please format your code.

Comment: I mean, seriously, what made you think that it was appropriate to show us your code _and to ask for help with it_ when it's in this abominable state?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to pass `std::vector` and `std::list` as types.

They are not types; they are, themselves, templates of types.

Many examples exist on the internet of passing standard containers as template arguments. Now you know what to look for. :)